# Изменение курсора в окне FigureCanvasTkAgg

Tags: python, tkinter

Здравствуйте. Пишу маленькую гуишку, которая строит графики при загрузке файлов.

Проблема - хочу, чтобы при нажатии кнопок "Нижний предел" и "Верхний предел" в окне, где строится график, изменялся курсор, и при нажатии на график менялся на стандартный. Непонятно, потому что у `FigureCanvasTkAgg` нет метода `config`  а в опциях нельзя установить курсор. Какие есть варианты?

```
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, 
NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from tkinter import *

class CustomToolbar(NavigationToolbar2TkAgg):
    toolitems = filter(lambda x: x[0] != "Home", 
    NavigationToolbar2TkAgg.toolitems)

class GUI:
    def __init__(self, parent):
       self.parent = parent
       self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

       f1 = Frame(self.parent, width=1000, height=500)
       f1.pack()

       global fig1, a, canvas
       fig1 = Figure(figsize=(6.5, 4.5))
       a = fig1.add_subplot(111)

       canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig1, master=self.parent)

       canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
       canvas.get_tk_widget().place(x=300, y=40)


       lbl1 = Button(f1, text='Нижний предел', command=self.connect_canv)
       lbl1.pack()
       lbl1.place(x=80, y=20)
       lbl2 = Button(f1, text='Верхний предел')
       lbl2.pack()
       lbl2.place(x=80, y=50)

       self.entry = Entry(f1, width=10)
       self.entry.pack()
       self.entry.place(x=10, y=20)
       self.entry2 = Entry(f1, width=10)
       self.entry2.pack()
       self.entry2.place(x=10, y=50)
       self.toolbar = CustomToolbar(canvas, self.parent)



   def plt_g(self, values, time):
       a.clear()
       a.plot(values, time)
       a.set_title("Current graphic", fontsize=15)
       a.set_ylabel("Signal", fontsize=13)
       a.set_xlabel("N", fontsize=13)

       canvas.draw()

   def getXY(self, event):
       x, y = event.inaxes.transData.inverted().transform((event.x, event.y))
       getx = event.x
       if self.entry.get() == '':
           self.entry.insert(0, str('%1.2f' % x))
           fig1.canvas.mpl_disconnect(cid)
       else:
           pass


   def connect_canv(self):
       self.entry.delete(0, END)
       global cid
       cid = fig1.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event',self.getXY)


def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("1000x560")
    root.resizable(0, 0)
    app = GUI(root)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
     main()
```

Comment: В сторону: глобальные переменные тут не нужны от слова совсем. Для того, чтобы имена были доступны во всей области видимости экземпляра класса принято делать их полями (аттрибутами). Пример: `self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, у `FigureCanvasTkAgg` нет `config/configure` метода, потому что он наследуется от `FigureCanvasAgg` и не обеспечивает `Tkinter-widget` интерфейса.

Вы же хотите работать с `tkinter.Canvas`, ссылку на который вы уже умеете получать. Вот пример из вышего кода:

```
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
canvas.get_tk_widget().place(x=300, y=40)
```

Точно таким же образом можно и менять вид курсора:

```
canvas.get_tk_widget().configure(cursor='pirate')
```

или:

```
canvas._tkcanvas.configure(cursor='pirate')
```

**UPD** Описанный выше метод устанавливает курсор для всего `canvas`. Если необходимо, чтобы курсор менялся только в области осей:

1. Необходимо переопределить метод `_set_cursor` для `CustomToolbar`:

   ```
   def _set_cursor(self, event):

       if event.inaxes and self._active == 'CUSTOM_LIMIT':
           self.window.configure(cursor='pirate')
           self._lastCursor = None
           return

       NavigationToolbar2TkAgg._set_cursor(self, event)
   ```
2. В методе `connect_canv` устанавливать флаг:

   ```
   self.toolbar._active = 'CUSTOM_LIMIT'
   ```

Comment: Спасибо! И еще маленький вопрос - canvas._tkcanvas().configure(cursor='pirate') устанавливает курсор на всей площади канваса. А если мне надо в пределах осей?